# Localize iOS App name in Unity

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, unity-game-engine, info.plist

I'm'developing a Unity3D game that shows a different (localized) app name in the iPhone's home screen according to the user local language. Note that:

1. I already know how to localize the iOS app name by editing the Xcode project (create a `InfoPlist.string` file, localize it, add the `CFBundleDisplayName` key to it, etc.)
2. I also know how **automatically** localize an Android app name within the Unity editor (add a `values-XX.xml` file with the `app_name` property onto `Assets/Plugins/Android/res/` folder, etc.)

The question is: how can I **automatically** localize my **iOS** app name within the **Unity Editor** so that I don't need to perform the error-prone task **1.** every time I build the project?

I think that `PostprocessBuildPlayer` should be the way to go, however I haven't found any documentation on how to parse it and/or modify the Xcode project file correctly to achieve this.

Comment: You might want to check out this asset: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28954

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago I ran into trouble when I tried to modify info.plist via the Build Player Pipeline especially when doing it in *Append mode*. It works only once and then subsequent builds fail with "*The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."* (s. Unity forum posts like [this one](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/facebook-sdk-build-couldnt-parse-contents.212169/) and my [blog posting](http://www.scio.de/en/blog-a-news/scio-development-blog-en/entry/unity-ios-build-problem-corrupted-info-plist) about this problem) So I decided to take the alternative way combining a customised build with an Xcode Build Pre-action.

Three steps are required:

### (1) Xcode setup:

In Xcode go to *Edit Scheme / Build / Pre-actions*. Then click the + sign to add a *New Run Script Action*.

- In *Provide build settings* select *Unity-iPhone*.
- Paste `. ${PROJECT_DIR}/modify_info_plist.sh` (note the dot and blank at the beginning, is ensures that the script is executed in the caller's shell)

So it should look like this:
[image: Xcode screenshot]

### (2) Script modify_info_plist.sh:

Within your script you have access to all environmet variables from Xcode (s. [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW108)) and you can manipulate Info.plist using the `defaults` command ([man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html)). Here is a sample I used to add `gyroscope` to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`:

```
# Code snippet used in Unity-iPhone scheme as "Build Pre-Action"

my_domain=${PROJECT_DIR}/Info.plist
status_bar_key=UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance

logger "Start adding keys to info.plist"
defaults write $my_domain $status_bar_key -boolean NO

if [ `defaults read $my_domain UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities | grep "gyroscope" | wc -l` = "0" ]; then
    defaults write $my_domain UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities -array-add  "gyroscope"
fi
logger "Keys added to info.plist successfully"
```

### (3) Build Pipeline:

Put the following code in a static editor class to create a new menu item Tools / My iOS Build with shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>:

```
static string IOSBuildDir= "Develop";

[MenuItem("Tools/My iOS Build %&b")]
public static void IOSBuild () {
    string[] levels = { "Assets/Scenes/Boot.unity",
        "Assets/Scenes/Level-1.unity",
        // ...
        "Assets/Scenes/Menu.unity"
    };
    string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory ();
    path += "/" + IOSBuildDir + "/Info.plist";
    if (File.Exists (path)) {
        Debug.Log ("Removing file " + path);
        File.Delete (path);
    }
    BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer (levels, "Develop", BuildTarget.iPhone, 
        BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer);
}
```

---

I know this is no perfect solution but it's the only one I found to work stable. Two drawbacks:

- Step **(1)** has to be repeated after major Xcode format changes
- New scenes have to be appended in the editor class code in step **(3)**